# Upgrade : Tapestry 5.1.0.5 to Tapestry 5.2.6

Tags: tapestry

I am trying to upgrade the tapestry version from 5.1.0.5 to 5.2.6. I have read the release notes of the version and applied appropriate changes to the project.

Now when I am starting my application, its giving a following exception at runtime on login page itself :

```
   org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueException: Render queue error in SetupRender[core/ExceptionReport:exceptiondisplay]: Unable to create a client URL for classpath resource jquery-1.3.2.js: The resource path was not within an aliased path. [at classpath:org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/pages/ExceptionReport.tml, line 11]
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:84)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderQueueImpl.render(PageRenderQueueImpl.java:127)
    $PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b801.render($PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b801.java)
    $PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b7f9.render($PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b7f9.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MarkupRendererTerminator.renderMarkup(MarkupRendererTerminator.java:37)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$29.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2089)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$28.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2073)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$27.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2055)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$26.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2040)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$25.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2026)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$24.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2008)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$23.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1989)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b800.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b800.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageMarkupRendererImpl.renderPageMarkup(PageMarkupRendererImpl.java:47)
    $PageMarkupRenderer_134b2c5b7fe.renderPageMarkup($PageMarkupRenderer_134b2c5b7fe.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageResponseRendererImpl.renderPageResponse(PageResponseRendererImpl.java:67)
    $PageResponseRenderer_134b2c5b70d.renderPageResponse($PageResponseRenderer_134b2c5b70d.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:85)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_134b2c5b6ea.handleRequestException($RequestExceptionHandler_134b2c5b6ea.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:42)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$4.service(TapestryModule.java:984)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:974)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:90)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:80)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:85)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:103)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6e2.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6e2.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:272)
    org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:44)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    net.fckeditor.connector.Tapestry5InterceptFckActivityFilter.service(Tapestry5InterceptFckActivityFilter.java:133)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_134b2c5b6df.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_134b2c5b6df.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:928)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6dd.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6dd.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:147)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    com.netexcompany.kubbe.web.util.RememberMeFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    com.netexcompany.kubbe.web.util.SSOFilter.doFilterHttp(SSOFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Unable to create a client URL for classpath resource jquery-1.3.2.js: The resource path was not within an aliased path. [at classpath:org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/pages/ExceptionReport.tml, line 11]
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:194)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$SetupRenderPhase.render(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:222)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:72)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderQueueImpl.render(PageRenderQueueImpl.java:127)
    $PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b801.render($PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b801.java)
    $PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b7f9.render($PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b7f9.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MarkupRendererTerminator.renderMarkup(MarkupRendererTerminator.java:37)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$29.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2089)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$28.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2073)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$27.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2055)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$26.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2040)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$25.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2026)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$24.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2008)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$23.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1989)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b800.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b800.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageMarkupRendererImpl.renderPageMarkup(PageMarkupRendererImpl.java:47)
    $PageMarkupRenderer_134b2c5b7fe.renderPageMarkup($PageMarkupRenderer_134b2c5b7fe.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageResponseRendererImpl.renderPageResponse(PageResponseRendererImpl.java:67)
    $PageResponseRenderer_134b2c5b70d.renderPageResponse($PageResponseRenderer_134b2c5b70d.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:85)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_134b2c5b6ea.handleRequestException($RequestExceptionHandler_134b2c5b6ea.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:42)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$4.service(TapestryModule.java:984)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:974)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:90)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:80)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:85)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:103)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6e2.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6e2.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:272)
    org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:44)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    net.fckeditor.connector.Tapestry5InterceptFckActivityFilter.service(Tapestry5InterceptFckActivityFilter.java:133)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_134b2c5b6df.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_134b2c5b6df.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:928)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6dd.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6dd.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:147)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    com.netexcompany.kubbe.web.util.RememberMeFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    com.netexcompany.kubbe.web.util.SSOFilter.doFilterHttp(SSOFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.util.UnknownValueException: Unable to create a client URL for classpath resource jquery-1.3.2.js: The resource path was not within an aliased path.
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ClasspathAssetAliasManagerImpl.toClientURL(ClasspathAssetAliasManagerImpl.java:112)
    $ClasspathAssetAliasManager_134b2c5b6f5.toClientURL($ClasspathAssetAliasManager_134b2c5b6f5.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ClasspathAssetFactory.buildDefaultPath(ClasspathAssetFactory.java:94)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ClasspathAssetFactory.clientURL(ClasspathAssetFactory.java:71)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ClasspathAssetFactory.access$000(ClasspathAssetFactory.java:34)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ClasspathAssetFactory$1.toClientURL(ClasspathAssetFactory.java:108)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.javascript.JavaScriptStackPathConstructorImpl$1.map(JavaScriptStackPathConstructorImpl.java:45)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.javascript.JavaScriptStackPathConstructorImpl$1.map(JavaScriptStackPathConstructorImpl.java:42)
    org.apache.tapestry5.func.LazyMappedValue.get(LazyMappedValue.java:31)
    org.apache.tapestry5.func.LazyFlow.first(LazyFlow.java:52)
    org.apache.tapestry5.func.AbstractFlow$1.next(AbstractFlow.java:68)
    org.apache.tapestry5.func.AbstractFlow.toMutableList(AbstractFlow.java:47)
    org.apache.tapestry5.func.AbstractFlow.toMutableList(AbstractFlow.java:40)
    org.apache.tapestry5.func.AbstractFlow.toList(AbstractFlow.java:205)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.javascript.JavaScriptStackPathConstructorImpl.toPaths(JavaScriptStackPathConstructorImpl.java:76)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.javascript.JavaScriptStackPathConstructorImpl.constructPathsForJavaScriptStack(JavaScriptStackPathConstructorImpl.java:70)
    $JavaScriptStackPathConstructor_134b2c5b802.constructPathsForJavaScriptStack($JavaScriptStackPathConstructor_134b2c5b802.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ajax.JavaScriptSupportImpl.addAssetsFromStack(JavaScriptSupportImpl.java:294)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ajax.JavaScriptSupportImpl.addCoreStackIfNeeded(JavaScriptSupportImpl.java:279)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ajax.JavaScriptSupportImpl.importJavaScriptLibrary(JavaScriptSupportImpl.java:232)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ajax.JavaScriptSupportImpl.importJavaScriptLibrary(JavaScriptSupportImpl.java:227)
    $JavaScriptSupport_134b2c5b83d.importJavaScriptLibrary($JavaScriptSupport_134b2c5b83d.java)
    $JavaScriptSupport_134b2c5b72e.importJavaScriptLibrary($JavaScriptSupport_134b2c5b72e.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ImportWorker$1.work(ImportWorker.java:52)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ImportWorker$1.work(ImportWorker.java:49)
    org.apache.tapestry5.func.ArrayFlow.each(ArrayFlow.java:66)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ImportWorker$6.invoke(ImportWorker.java:221)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.InternalClassTransformationImpl$9.advise(InternalClassTransformationImpl.java:2370)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.java:86)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.RenderPhaseMethodWorker$RenderPhaseMethodAdvice.advise(RenderPhaseMethodWorker.java:72)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.java:86)
    org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.ExceptionDisplay.setupRender(ExceptionDisplay.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$SetupRenderPhase.invokeComponent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:215)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:176)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$SetupRenderPhase.render(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:222)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:72)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderQueueImpl.render(PageRenderQueueImpl.java:127)
    $PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b801.render($PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b801.java)
    $PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b7f9.render($PageRenderQueue_134b2c5b7f9.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MarkupRendererTerminator.renderMarkup(MarkupRendererTerminator.java:37)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$29.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2089)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$28.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2073)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$27.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2055)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$26.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2040)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$25.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2026)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$24.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2008)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$23.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1989)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b803.java)
    $MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b800.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_134b2c5b800.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageMarkupRendererImpl.renderPageMarkup(PageMarkupRendererImpl.java:47)
    $PageMarkupRenderer_134b2c5b7fe.renderPageMarkup($PageMarkupRenderer_134b2c5b7fe.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageResponseRendererImpl.renderPageResponse(PageResponseRendererImpl.java:67)
    $PageResponseRenderer_134b2c5b70d.renderPageResponse($PageResponseRenderer_134b2c5b70d.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:85)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_134b2c5b6ea.handleRequestException($RequestExceptionHandler_134b2c5b6ea.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:42)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$4.service(TapestryModule.java:984)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:974)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:90)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:80)
    org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:85)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:103)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6ec.java)
    $RequestHandler_134b2c5b6e2.service($RequestHandler_134b2c5b6e2.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:272)
    org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:44)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    net.fckeditor.connector.Tapestry5InterceptFckActivityFilter.service(Tapestry5InterceptFckActivityFilter.java:133)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_134b2c5b6df.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_134b2c5b6df.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:928)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6e4.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6dd.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_134b2c5b6dd.java)
    org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:147)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    com.netexcompany.kubbe.web.util.RememberMeFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    com.netexcompany.kubbe.web.util.SSOFilter.doFilterHttp(SSOFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

From web I get this [link](http://markmail.org/thread/rq4vp7hi437smsrh#query%3a+page:1+mid%3ajldqua5f2qecsdbr+state%3aresults) where I am able to find the similar problem where somebody has asked to add `contributeClasspathAssetAliasManager` method. So I have tried to add that method in my AppModule.java :

```
 public static void contributeClasspathAssetAliasManager(MappedConfiguration<String, String> configuration) {
        configuration.add("js", "assets");
    }
```

But still the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a dependency of `easy-fckeditor`, whose latest revision (1.0.6 snapshot) is not supporting tapestry's latest version, due to this I was getting above exception.

Removed 'easy-fckeditor' dependency from maven based project and solved quite a few error after upgrading to 5.2.6 and application working fine.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to reference your JS file, and does its path match with the asset alias configuration? The way you have configured it, the JS would have to be at `${WEB_ROOT}/assets/jquery-1.3.2.js`, and you'd have to reference it like this:

```
@Import(library = "context:/js/jquery-1.3.2.js")
```

Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Well in my whole app i haven't added jquery-1.3.2.js at all

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using it, then it is more than likely within some component that you are using. Within your ide or os do a file search for jquery-1.3.2.js. If you are using a *nix based operating system, you can use the following code snippet to search within jar files. Save it in a file called search.sh inside your WEB-INF/lib folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.jar ; do
    jar tf $i | grep jquery-1.3.2.js
done
```

Then run `chmod +x search.sh` and finally `./search.sh` from within the lib folder.

Assuming it lists something like `com/some/component/jquery-1.3.2.js` which you find is in some-lib-2.0.jar add this to your Module file:

```
public static void contributeClasspathAssetAliasManager(MappedConfiguration<String, String> configuration) {
    configuration.add("some-lib/1.0", "com/some/component");
}
```